# How to implement 2 factor Authentication for Azure Virtual Network VPN?

Tags: vpn, azure

hoping someone can help point me in the right direction.  I have an azure virtual network and have downloaded the VPN client.  However we would really like to add 2 factor authentication as a requirement for VPN into this azure virtual network.  Any ideas how I might go about this as I haven't been able to google anything helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only authenticate Azure VPN P2S through the use of certificates there's no way to add 2 factor auth. There's not even login/password for user sign-in.

This feature is still under review:

http://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-azure-networking/suggestions/5314840-provide-multi-factor-authentication-capabilities-i

Comment: that's pretty much what I discovered, but I figure there has got to be a way to have 2 factor authentication for P2S somehow in Azure in order to pass high security clearances.

Comment: I don't think it's supported but you should take a look at multi-factor docs. There's a few scenarios regarding the use of multi-factor for vpn but they are intended to be used with RRAS and not Azure VNet. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/multi-factor-authentication-get-started/

Comment: Here's another proof that is not yet supported. http://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-azure-networking/suggestions/5314840-provide-multi-factor-authentication-capabilities-i. Still under review since last year.